# Circuit with resistance equal to input resistance

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistance, potentiometer, digital-potentiometer

I want to use a digital potentiometer, however, the digital potentiometer has a power limit, which means I can't apply the voltage for my application.

I am looking for a circuit which functions as an "resistance follower": depending on the resistance you input (that resistance should draw low current through it), the voltage source will "see" a resistance equal to that resistance. In other words, the current will follow Ohm's law.
(PD: The impedance can be just proportional and not just equal to the input resistance).

I was thinking of a voltage-controlled current source, where the voltage is proportional to the input resistance, something like this:

[image]

In this circuit Vinput/Iinput is proportional to Potentiometer R4 (in my understanding). An additional problem is the big voltage created at the output of U1.

The details are as follows: The voltage input will be maximum ~25 V, PWM of max 20 Hz.
Resistance can be 100-5000 Ω. Digital pot = AD5292.

To be more specific on the application, as requested: I want to use the AD2592 with a voltage of 25 V which is above its current limit of 3 mA (using a 100 Ω value). Ideally this digital pot should withstand 250 mA.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the application?  What are you really trying to accomplish?  The reason I ask is that most of the times I see a request for a resistance follower, it turns out to be an XY problem that can better be solved with more conventional approaches.

Comment: Unsaturated BJTs can act like variable resistors, that's how they follow voltage.

Comment: Being more specific on the application: I want to use a digital pot (AD5292) but with a current >3mA (Max current for that digital pot. Ideally a max current of 250mA. My best guess was to use a resistance follower.

Comment: You're still looking at the trees. We need you to look at the forest, please. What is the **ultimate** problem you need to solve? Please read this: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: What do you intend to use this resistance for?

Comment: @Eduardo Do you expect this to operate in two quadrants? Also, a VCCS doesn't seem right from what you say about it acting like a resistance. A resistor will vary its current based upon variations of the applied voltage. But a VCCS won't act like that. I must be missing something.